# Accessing an element of JSON returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I tried to access an element of my JSON but it returns undefined. In the following example, I wanted to do `console.log(myObj[0].voltage)` to get `13.48` but it returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my `data.json` file.

```
["{\"date\": \"2020-03-02T16:06:42.307916\", \"voltage\": 13.48}"]
```

And here is my `js` file.

```
function getjson() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    req.open("get", "data.json", true); 
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(myObj);
            console.log(myObj[0]);
            console.log(typeof myObj);
            console.log(myObj[0].voltage);
        }
    }
    req.send(null);
}
```

`console.log(myObj)` returns `["{\"date\": \"2020-03-02T16:06:42.307916\", \"voltage\": 13.48}"]`.

`console.log(myObj[0])` returns `{"date": "2020-03-02T16:06:42.307916", "voltage": 13.48}`.

`console.log(typeof myObj)` returns `object`.

And finally `console.log(myObj[0].voltage)` returns `undefined`, which I cannot figure out why.

Comment: `myObj` is an array with a single string element. You'll need to call `JSON.parse(myObj[0])`. Why? No idea, that's how your JSON file was created, the way the server serves JSON files, something like that.

Comment: Your JSON data is an array containing one string. You were presumably expecting it to be an array containing one object but the thing inside the square brackets is actually a string.

Answer (score 1):

Because the array contains just a stringified object.

In order to work you will have to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method to get the js object.

```
const jsObject = JSON.parse(data.json[0]);
jsObject.voltage // 13.48
```

Please try it here:

```js
const data = {
 json: ["{\"date\": \"2020-03-02T16:06:42.307916\", \"voltage\": 13.48}"]
}

console.log(data.json);

const jsObject = JSON.parse(data.json[0]);

console.log(jsObject.voltage);
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment! Also it turned out my json was in wrong format. It had to be `[{"date": "2020-03-02T16:06:42.307916", "voltage": 13.48}]` instead of `["{\"date\": \"2020-03-02T16:06:42.307916\", \"voltage\": 13.48}"]`. Everything works ok now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering myself. It turned out my json was in wrong format. The following works fine.

My `json`

`[{"date": "2020-03-02T16:06:42.307916", "voltage": 13.48}]`

My `js`

```
function getjson() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    req.open("get", "data.json", true); 
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(myObj[0].voltage); # It returns 13.48
        }
    }
    req.send(null);
}
```